# Beginner C#, Adding data to table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to add data to my database table 'modules' through data entered or clicked in my asp.net text fields and dropdown boxes. When I click the *update* button it redirects to the 'all-modules.aspx' page as coded but does not enter data into the database (table). Am i right in using the INSERT into statement? I have a feeling I am supposed to do something different with that statement and that I may be referencing a stored procedure that I haven't created. Keep in mind I am new to C# and asp.net and that this may be a daft question but I am stuck.

**asp.net**

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="menu" runat="Server">
    <!-- Your Code goes here -->
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="main_content" runat="Server">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="semesterlist" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT semester FROM semesters"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="yearlist" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT year_title FROM year"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="modulestatus" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT modulestatus FROM modulestatus"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="compulsorylist" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT compulsory FROM courses_vs_modules"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                Add Module</h1>
            <h5 class="subheading">Please use the form below to add a module:</h5>
            <div class="feedback blue" id="feedback" runat="server" visible="false">
                <asp:Label ID="feedback_text" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="col-9">
            <div class="panel">
                <h3>Fill out Module Details:</h3>

                <h5>Module Name:</h5>
                <asp:TextBox CssClass="full-width" ID="module_nametext" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                <h5>Module Tutor:</h5>
                <asp:TextBox CssClass="full-width" ID="module_tutortext" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                <h5>Compulsory:</h5>
                <asp:DropDownList CssClass="full-width" ID="compulsoryddl" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Optional</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Compulsory</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

                <h5>Semester:</h5>
                <asp:DropDownList CssClass="full-width" ID="semesterddl" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Semester 1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Semester 2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Semester 3</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

                <h5>Year:</h5>
                <asp:DropDownList CssClass="full-width" ID="yearddl" runat="server" DataSourceID="yearlist" DataTextField="year_title" DataValueField="year_title"></asp:DropDownList>

                <h5>Cats Points:</h5>
                <asp:TextBox CssClass="full-width" ID="cats_pointstext" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                <h5>Description:</h5>
                <asp:TextBox CssClass="full-width" ID="descriptiontext" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" MaxLength="500"></asp:TextBox>

                <h5>Module Status:</h5>
                <asp:DropDownList CssClass="full-width" ID="modulestatusddl" runat="server" DataSourceID="modulestatus" DataTextField="modulestatus" DataValueField="modulestatus"></asp:DropDownList>

                <asp:Button ID="updatebuttonmodule" runat="server" Text="Add Module" OnClick="updatebuttonmodule_Click" Visible="true"/>

            </div>
        </div>

</asp:Content>
```

**C#**

```
protected void updatebuttonmodule_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        feedback.Visible = true;
        feedback_text.Text = "Please ensure you've filled out all fields. ";

        string module_name = module_nametext.Text;
        string module_tutor = module_tutortext.Text;
        string year = yearddl.SelectedValue;
        string compulsory = compulsoryddl.SelectedValue;
        string semester = semesterddl.SelectedValue;
        string cats_points = cats_pointstext.Text;
        string description = descriptiontext.Text;
        string modulestatus = modulestatusddl.SelectedValue;

        string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        myConnection.Open();

        string AddModule = "INSERT into modules (module_name,module_tutor,compulsory,semester,year,cats_points,description,module_status) " +
                   " VALUES ('" + module_name + "', '" + module_tutor + "', '" + compulsory + "' '" + semester + "', '" + year + "', '" + cats_points + "', '" + description + "', '" + modulestatus + "',);";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(AddModule, myConnection);

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", year);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@module_name", module_name);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@module_tutor", module_tutor);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compulsory", compulsory);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@semester", semester);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cats_points", cats_points);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", description);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modulestatus", modulestatus);

        try
        {
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch { 
        myConnection.Close();

        Response.Redirect("all-modules.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Comment: it looks like, if you're getting redirected to `all-modules`, that an exception is thrown. Have you tried debugging and stepping through the insert a line at a time?

Comment: At the bottom you have a try catch. The `catch` part of that will catch any errors in your `try` and perform the code inside the `catch` when the error happens. With what you've done here, you're hiding those errors, closing your connection and redirecting instead. Remove the try catch, and read the error output from your site to determine what is going wrong.

Comment: If you **add** data, then use an INSERT statement. If you are changing values, then use an UPDATE.

Comment: This means the db transaction fails. You have the redirect in the catch. Catch is used to catch errors that happen in the try  block. If you want to display the error you can do `catch(Exception ex){ Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)}`

Comment: You're not really adding parameters either... you're plugging the input from the textbox directly into the insert query, and then you're adding parameters - which is moot...

Comment: Added 'catch(Exception ex){ Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)}' displaying 0 errors, warnings and messages. I am trying to add data @krillgar not udpate.

Comment: @ragerory what is a better practice then?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine()` won't do anything for you in a web forms environment.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems. You're not wrapping things in `using` statements, you're open to Sql injection attacks, and you have redundant code. You're redirecting during your `catch` block, which means something went wrong. Trying something like the following:

```
protected void updateButtonModule_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    feedback.Visible = true;
    feedback_text.Text = "Please ensure you've filled out all fields. ";

    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) // using automatically disposes of object
    {
        myConnection.Open();

        string addModule = "INSERT into modules (module_name,module_tutor,compulsory,semester,year,cats_points,description,module_status)" +
                           "VALUES (@module_name,@module_tutor,@compulsory,@semester,@year,@cats_points,@description,@modulestatus)"; // use parameters to avoid sql injection

        using (var myCommand = new SqlCommand(addModule, myConnection))
        {
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", yearddl.SelectedValue);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@module_name", module_nametext.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@module_tutor", module_tutortext.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compulsory", compulsoryddl.SelectedValue);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@semester", semesterddl.SelectedValue);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cats_points", cats_pointstext.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", descriptiontext.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modulestatus", modulestatusddl.SelectedValue);

            try
            {
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex) // catch specific exceptions
            { 
                // do something with error here
                // Response.Write(ex.Message); 
            }
        }
    }

    Response.Redirect("all-modules.aspx");
}
```

Also, you should have a separate project for DataAccess, and be referencing that instead of having your connections in the code behind. So, that button code should really be something like `provider.Update(params);` which makes a call to that, but that is a different question.

Comment: Also make sure that your `SqlParameters` match the type of data you're putting into the fields. If they do not match, they will break your insert.

Comment: When i use 'using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) // using automatically disposes of object' it doesnt declare it so i can't use 'myConnection.Open(); properly. What am I doing wrong here? I thought that line was declaring the myConnection local variable.?

Comment: I was missing a parentheses on the using statements. I've added them in. That is probably it.

Comment: Also note I changed the variable name of `ConnectionString` to `connectionString` for readability (same with `addModule`).

Comment: I amended your changes, again there is no errors. I'm absolutely baffled why this wont add data to the database. Should I instead use a dataset?

Comment: No errors? Did you uncomment `Response.Write(ex.Message)` in the catch block?

Comment: I can guarantee this code works, it's standard `ADO.NET`. Do *not* use `DataSet`. If you just copied and pasted my code, you will not see errors because the catch block is commented out. So, let's take a step back... Does this method even get executed? Is your connection string working? Have you placed a breakpoint on the first line and stepped through the code?

Comment: The method seems to be getting executed. My connection string is 100% confirmed working. Yes but the code doesn't break there is no errors? I used Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); to try and get more info, but still no information.

Comment: What do you mean by "seems to be getting executed"? It either does or it doesn't. Did you place a breakpoint in that method and step through?

Comment: You also realize that `Console.WriteLine` will not do *anything* in a web forms environment, right?

Comment: OK this is slightly interesting, when I click to update the database through my button in the UI it posts 'Please ensure you've filled out all fields.' as expected through feedback.Visible = true;
        feedback_text.Text = "Please ensure you've filled out all fields. "; If I have not entered data in 1 or many fields. However I have entered or set data in every field, do you think that my fields are corrupt or is it potentially my datasources that are the problem?

Comment: 'You also realize that Console.WriteLine will not do anything in a web forms environment, right? –' Just read your comment under my original post. Apologies.

Comment: Set it to `Response.Write(ex.Message);`, rerun your test and see if you get any text at the top of your page. If you do not, there are one of two issues; your connection string is not correct, or your data types do not match your sql field types. Are all the fields you are inserting to `nvarchar`?

Comment: Its throwing up my INSERT statement in red.

Comment: So, you *are* getting an error. Your datatypes are probably off. Any chance your `year` or `cat_points` columns are of type int or something other than varchar/nvarchar?

Comment: Yes my year, cat_points, semester and module_status are of type int

Comment: Ok, you are passing them as string (see: `("@year", yearddl.SelectedValue)` - pass those as ints and you will not have a problem anymore.

Comment: Thanks ! Can you give an example of how to pass them as integers?

Comment: C'mon man. Google it. I think I've helped way more than anyone else on this site would.

Comment: Ok Rory, thanks for your help, I will refer to Google!

Comment: Marking as answer would be great too!

Comment: I do not see myCommand.Type = CommandType.text; SqlServer does not know what command type this is

Comment: @Gregg default is Text.